# Python - slice a list of list

Tags: python, list, slice

I think its called a slice...

basically I have a list of lists:

```
[['fmt/10', 3L, 5L, Decimal('9500')], 
['fmt/353', 1L, 1L, Decimal('500')], 
['fmt/7', 3L, 5L, Decimal('9500')], 
['fmt/8', 3L, 5L, Decimal('9500')], 
['fmt/9', 3L, 5L, Decimal('9500')]]
```

and I want to pull out 4 new lists, all at position [0], [1], [2] and [3].

so if would look like:

```
A = ['fmt/10', 'fmt/353','fmt/7','fmt/8','fmt/9']
B = [3,1,3,3,3] 
C = [5,1,5,5,5]
D = [9500,500,9500,9500,9500]
```

Whats the simplest way to achieve this? 
From reading around I think I want to use 'zip' but I'm not sure how that works.

Comment: By the way, this is called matrix transposition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
L = [['fmt/10', 3L, 5L, Decimal('9500')], 
     ['fmt/353', 1L, 1L, Decimal('500')], 
     ['fmt/7', 3L, 5L, Decimal('9500')], 
     ['fmt/8', 3L, 5L, Decimal('9500')], 
     ['fmt/9', 3L, 5L, Decimal('9500')]]
```

`zip(*L)` (the asterisk is being used to unpack the list) will give:

```
[('fmt/10', 'fmt/353', 'fmt/7', 'fmt/8', 'fmt/9'),
 (3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
 (5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L),
 (Decimal('9500'), Decimal('500'), Decimal('9500'), Decimal('9500'), Decimal('9500'))]
```

and you may use the destructuring assignment:

```
A, B, C, D = zip(*L)
```

Comment: And it really is that simple. Thank you! Of course it works as expected.

Comment: yup, otherwise you would have to do something like [[l[i] for l in L] for i in range(4)]

Answer (score 1):

```
A, B, C, D = apply(zip, [['fmt/10', 3L, 5L, Decimal('9500')], 
                         ['fmt/353', 1L, 1L, Decimal('500')], 
                         ['fmt/7', 3L, 5L, Decimal('9500')], 
                         ['fmt/8', 3L, 5L, Decimal('9500')], 
                         ['fmt/9', 3L, 5L, Decimal('9500')]])
```

Comment: Note: the python documentation states that apply() has been deprecated since python2.3 and unpacking with * should be used instead. The apply function was removed in python3.